# Are AWS EC2 AMIs automatically shared as community AMIs?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EBS-backed instance of a Windows server running under EC2.

When I make an AMI from this instance, the new AMI appears under "My AMIs" as expected, but I notice it also appears in the "Community AMIs" list.

Does this mean my AMI has automatically been shared with the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You're just able to see your AMI in community AMIs because you have permissions to see it. Observe these two screenshots. I created an AMI in the first account and it shows up in my Community AMIs for that account. I then logged on with a different account and attempted to search for the same AMI but that account was unable to see it.

[image: Account that created the AMI]
[image: Other account trying to find the AMI]